# XHR error (404 Not Found) loading node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js/modal.js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular2-template, ngx-bootstrap

Here I get the above Error while I'm installing ngx

**Package.json**

```
 "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.8.1",
```

**System.config.js**

//This is My ngx-bootstrap

```
   'ngx-bootstrap': 'npm:ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js',
```

Here im Getting Error as'ngx-bootstrap': 'npm:ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js/modal.js',

My Previous Links

```
 '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
```

please Guide me, from where I'm doing mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you import `ModalModule` from in your @NgModule?
Looks like you're importing it from `ngx-bootstrap/modal`. System.JS users have to import modules directly from `ngx-bootstrap`, just as official demo says http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#usage